# Arriving in Netherlands on French Visa Type D Mult

Tags: long-stay-visas

I got my visa Type D Mult for Talent/Researcher from France since I will be starting my postdoc there. But my contract signing is on 6th January. So I want to go to Netherlands on Christmas to my fiancée.

If I land in Amsterdam on this bus, would it be a problem? 
Dates of the visa are okay and not an issue.

Comment: Since this question is about a D-Visa (long term) it should be moved to **Expatriates Stack Exchange**

Comment: @MarkJohnson it's on topic on both sites.  It's about a short term trip by someone who is a long term resident somewhere else.  If the mere mention of a D visa automatically made questions off topic here, there would be no need for the [tag:long-stay-visas] tag.

Comment: Kunal, does your visa's period of validity begin before Christmas?

Comment: @phoog The 'someone' is a Expatriate in this case, thus the answer **does not apply** to travelers with a C-Visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson that is correct. But the question is about travel nonetheless. If you think the question is off topic, why did you answer it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is fine.

With a D-Visa (as apposed to a C-Visa) you are allowed to remain in the Schengen country that issued it (France) during the whole period the visa is valid for.

During this period, you are also allowed to visit other Schengen countries, based on the 90/180 days rule for the days **outside** the issuing country (France).

In reality, only when some authority has **good reasons** to believe that you have overstayed (4 months in same hotel in Amsterdam), will anything be undertaken.
In such a case the burden of proof then lies with you.